# Java: extend LocalDate (LocalDateTime) class

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

Is it possible to extend JDK 1.8 `LocalDate` class without wrapping it?

```
public class UserLocalDate extends LocalDate implements UserType { 
    //Cannot inhertit from final java.time.LocalDate
}
```

The class is `final` so it can't be extended directly. Is there a similar abstract class to extend from or some other way to get a class with just the same methods?

What I'm trying to do is to create a Hibernate custom `UserType` date class which will be a `LocalDate` inside runtime environment and will be stored into database as an integer generated using specific rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement the ChronoLocalDate interface, however wrapping the class is likely to be your best option.

Comment: Yes, I use wrapping. Implementing `ChronoLocalDate` sounds like writing my own `LocalDate` from sketch.

Comment: @OlegMikhailov I would only implement he methods you actually need/use. Implementing the whole of `ChronoLocalDate` is likely to be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot extend LocalDate, so that your implementation is a `LocalDate` in your environment. Even when implementing `ChronoLocalDate` your implementation would *not* be a `LocalDate`.

Why don't you just store the `LocalDate`in your database as a date db value? Which Hibernate version are you using? Since Hibernate version 5, these date types are supported, and if you are using an older version, you could use an *AttributeConverter*. I wrote a [blog post](http://www.sothawo.com/2015/01/using-the-new-java8-date-time-classes-with-hibernate/) about this some time ago, you might want to check this way.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Hibernate 5, but the date should be stored as 4-byte `integer`, not as a date type. I used `AttributeConverter` before, but now I find it easier to implement Hibernate `UserType` with `LocalDate` wrapped inside.